# Trouble importing GDAL and ogr using Jyupter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, gdal

I am working on a school project doing some spatial analysis on of counties in California; using Jyupter Notebook to run Python(2.7) scripts and create visualizations.

I was successful in importing Basemap into my notebook after I downloaded it using conda. I am very new to Python and can't really remember how I pulled that off. I believe I used the instructions from [this website](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap).

But now, when trying to impose my shapefile over the basemap I run into this error:

```
ValueError: shapefile must have lat/lon vertices  - it looks like this one has vertices in map projection coordinates. You can convert the shapefile to geographic
coordinates using the shpproj utility from the shapelib tools
(http://shapelib.maptools.org/shapelib-tools.html)
```

For the past hour I have been searching for ways to convert the coordinates and learned about GDAL and some command `ogr2ogr`. I have tried following the instructions posted on [gdal.org](https://gdal.org/download.html#conda) that tell me to run this command: `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`. Is there a difference between conda and conda-forge? I have tried many variations of this command like: `conda install -c anaconda2 gdal` and `install conda gdal`. Nothing has worked because when I go back to my notebook and try `import gdal` or `import ogr` I get an error like so:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgif.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda2/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm really confused as to how conda works, the difference between conda and conda-forge, and where all this stuff I have been downloading has been going. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when you ask a question, please specify your environment: OS, conda version (`conda info`), Python version, etc.

#### What is a channel

`conda` is a Python environment manager and a package manager. To install packages, `conda` has to download the packages from somewhere. The place where `conda` get the list of packages is called a channel.

By defaults, two channels named `main` and `r` are enable, both of which are maintained by Anaconda, the company itself. `conda-force` is a channel by a third-party community.

[Quote from conda-force documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html)

> What is conda-forge?
>
> conda-forge is a community effort that provides conda packages for a wide range of software.

Specify a channel in command line with `-c channelname`, shortcut for `--channel`.

#### How to fix your problem

Your problem was caused by a mixed channel usage for one package. `gdal` was specified to be installed from `conda-forge`, but not its dependencies. Since channel of its dependencies are not specified, the default channel `main` and `r` will be used.

To fix the mixed dependency use, enable "strict" channel priority.

```sh
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

which makes channel specified by `--channel` prioritize over other channels.

> `channel_priority` (ChannelPriority)
>
> With `strict` channel priority, packages in lower
>   priority channels are not considered if a package with the same name
>   appears in a higher priority channel.

Then recreate an environment and install `gdal`.

```sh
conda create --name test4gdal python=2.7
conda activate test4gdal
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

This time, all `gdal` related packages are installed from `conda-forge`.

#### References

- [Get started with conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)
- [conda-forge documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html)
- [import error from geopandas, mac os, anaconda](https://github.com/conda-forge/geopandas-feedstock/issues/45)

Comment: This response is really helpful. I am going to take a look at it further after classes this evening. I appreciate the references at the bottom as well.

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the helpful resources I've been able to figure out how to use conda which is a huge step. Marked as the best answer.